# Ordering in Python (2.4) dictionary

Tags: python

```
    r_dict={'answer1': "value1",'answer11': "value11",'answer2': "value2",'answer3': "value3",'answer4': "value4",}

    for i in r_dict:
        if("answer" in i.lower()):
           print i

  Result is answer11,answer2,snswer4,answer3
```

I am using Python 2.4.3. I there any way to get the order in which it is populated?

Or is there a way to do this by regular expression since I am using the older Python version?

Comment: Perhaps edit the title of the question to indicate you are on python 2.4.x or to indicate that collections.OrderedDict is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are unordered - that is, they do have some order, but it's influenced in nonobvious ways by the order of insertion and the hash of the keys. However, there is another implementation that remembers the order of insertion, [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Edit: For Python 2.4, there are several third party implementations. I haven't used any, but since [the one from voidspace](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html) looks promising.

Comment: he's on python 2.4.3.  OrderedDict is new as of 2.7.

Comment: +1 for voidspace's implementation.  I wasn't aware of that previously.

Answer (score 1):

Not just by using the dictionary by itself. Dictionaries in Python (and a good portion of equivalent non-specialized data structures that involve mapping) are not sorted.

You could potentially subclass `dict` and override the `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` methods to add/remove each key to an internal list where you maintain your own sorting.  You'd probably then have to override other methods, such as `__iter__` to get the sorting you want out of your for loop.

...or just use the [odict module](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html)  as [@delnan suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469633/ordering-in-python-dictionary/3469697#3469697)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is by construction unordered. If you want an ordered one, use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
import collections
r_dict = collections.OrderedDict( [ ( 'answer1', "value1"), ('answer11', "value11"), ('answer2', "value2"), ('answer3', "value3"), ('answer4', "value4") ] )

for i in r_dict:
    if("answer" in i.lower()):
        print i
```

Comment: I am using python 2.4.3 i think this may not be possible

Comment: `collections` was introduced in Python 2.4, I believe. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ah, apologies. `collections` was indeed introduced in Python 2.4, but `OrderedDict` wasn't added until 2.7. If you need this functionality, it's probably easiest to make a list of [(key, value)] tuples and handle uniqueness yourself.

Comment: The [ordereddict package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict) claims to be a drop-in replacement for the one in Python 2.7 (Raymond Hettinger is credited as the author of both implementations), and works for Python 2.4 and up.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. Python dictionaries are fundamentally unordered.