# Python dictionary storage

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordering in Python (2.4) dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469633/ordering-in-python-dictionary)

I tried to copy a `dict` to another but in a sorted way. I got the follwing problem.

```
mydict = {'carl':40,           
          'alan':2,           
          'bob':1,           
          'danny':3}
d1={}
for key in sorted(mydict):
    d1[key]=mydict[key]
```

When I print `d1` it shows:

```
{'bob': 1, 'danny': 3, 'carl': 40, 'alan': 2}
```

Why is it not in sorted order?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dicts have no order.
You have to use a [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: so what order does it takes by default? why is it not fuctioning like a stack?

Comment: The order is implementation defined.

Comment: Order should be considered random - a dict is like a hashtable, optimized for speed of access (O(1)).

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are not sorted. Use `collections.OrderedDict`

Answer (score 0):

Because `dict` doesn't remember the order that keys were first inserted. You need [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).